# How to procedurally attach text to generated gameobjects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have in my unity program created a bunch of cubes like this:

```
foreach (Cube cube in cubeList)
{
   if (cube.canStandOn)
   {
      GameObject block;
      block = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
      block.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
      block.transform.position = new Vector3(cube._mPos.x + CubeSize.half, cube._mPos.y + CubeSize.half, cube._mPos.z + CubeSize.half);
      block.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue;
   }
}
```

Now I want to add a text abvove ***each*** block detailing its position. The ammount of cubes and their positions could change every run so this has to be done programatically just like the how the blocks are created. I could not find anything on this `Text Mesh` seems like it would be a nice way to go but did not find any example created without having a previously created game object with a text mesh attatched. This is done in an android app so I cannot use the `OnGizmos()` function.

Doing it in `OnGUI()` might have been ok but that wont show up in the scene window which is where I want it as well.

any tips?

Comment: Is there a reason to not make a prefab which consists of a cube and a text part (this should probably be a UI text with the canvas render mode set to `World Space`)? This should also take care of camera rotation/facing towards the camera (if the camera can be rotated).

Comment: oh, so you mean I could add objects with this prefab to the scene several times while changing its position and text, and adding the "blocks" this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create another GameObject and make the cube its parent. Use `addComponent` to add `TextMesh` to that new GameObject under the cube.Assign the possible of the cube to the `TextMesh` then set the `y` a-xis of the `TextMesh` so that it will be on top of the cube. You also need to make `textMesh.anchor` and `textMesh.alignment` to be centered in the **middle** so that the `TextMesh` will be positioned with the cube.  Depending on the size of the cube, you may need to adjust the `textOffset` variable. without scaling the cube, it worked well on my side. If it doesn't work for you, just scale the scale the `TextMesh` like you scaled the cube.

```
int textOffset = 2;
foreach (Cube cube in cubeList)
{
   if (cube.canStandOn)
   {
      GameObject block;
      block = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
      block.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
      block.transform.position = new Vector3(cube._mPos.x + CubeSize.half, cube._mPos.y + CubeSize.half, cube._mPos.z + CubeSize.half);
      block.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue;

      ////////////////////////TEXT MESH CODE//////////////////////

        //Create new GameObject
        GameObject childObj = new GameObject();

        //Make block to be parent of this gameobject
        childObj.transform.parent = block.transform;
        childObj.name = "Text Holder";

        //Create TextMesh and modify its properties
        TextMesh textMesh = childObj.AddComponent<TextMesh>();
        textMesh.text = "Blah Blah Blah";
        textMesh.characterSize = 1;

        //Set postion of the TextMesh with offset
        textMesh.anchor = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;
        textMesh.alignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        textMesh.transform.position = new Vector3(block.transform.position.x,  block.transform.position.y + textOffset, block.transform.position.z);

   }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm even used the colour I wanted and everything. Thank you. I tried this method before but could not get it to work so I thought it was wrong.

Comment: @soncis Nope. It was fine. You were probably attaching the Text directly to the cube. It wont work like that. Also you must change the anchor and allignement. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a prefab that consists of a cube with a canvas as child (this in turn holds a UI text). Set the canvas render mode to `World Space`. Adjust the scale if all have the same. Preferably you actually create an empty gameobject and have the cube and the canvas be child of that.

To place the cube do something like this:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;     // required for the text component

public GameObject prefabCube;

...

Vector3 cubePos = new Vector3(x, y, z);
GameObject cube = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefabCube, cubePos, Quaternion.identity);
cube.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = x + " " + y + " " + z;    // not quite sure if this line is correct
cube.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue;     // if all blocks have the same color, change this for the prefab directly
// if you use an empty the last has to be
cube.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>().material.color = Color.blue;
```

This should be about correct.